# For all y ∈ S, if y < 1 and y ̸ = 0, then y is negative. Provide a domain S for which this claim is false.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm confused with this question... " Provide a domain S for which this claim is false. "

I stated the domain is S = { 0, 1, 2, ... inf } and was told this is incorrect and makes the statement true.

To get the above domain I negated "if y < 1 and y ̸ = 0, then y is negative"
( y < 1 and y /= 0 ) -> y is negative )
~( y < 1 and y /= 0 ) or y is negative )   The Implication Rule
y > 1 or Y = 0 or y is negative            De Morgan

any help?

Comment: You didn't "negate", you rewrote (with a small mistake at the end: it should be $y\ge1$). Now, take the negation of $\forall y\in S\quad(y\ge1\text{ or }y\le0)$ and provide a set $S$ for which this negation  holds.

Comment: negation of ∀y∈S(y≥1 or y≤0) would be:  There exist a y ∈S (y < 1 and y does /= 0 ) ?

Answer (score -1):

Hint: You are looking for a set that contains at least one number that is smaller than 1,  not 0, and not negative.  In other words, you need a number $0<x<1$.   Can you think of any such number?   Now, any domain that includes such a number will make that statement false.

Comment: 1/2    <--    "you need a number 0<x<1. Can you think of any such number?"

Comment: Now just throw that into any set and the statement is false because not every number in it that meets the "less than one and not zero test" is negative.

Comment: Alan thank you so much for your help ... but I'm still confused. The question is " Provide a domain S for which this claim is false. " .... so why cant I state { 0 ... inf } ?

Comment: If the question was " Provide a domain S within the domain x < 1 and X /=0 that makes the statement false. " would have been easer on the eyes for me ...

Comment: @legoSteve the statement is true for the domain 0,1,2... etc.  There are no counterexamples of a number in that domain